# How can I change copied number when pasting it into UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a number into UITextView from iPhone **Notes** app.

[screenshot: number copied from Notes app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFQ3.png)

But after copying and pasting it in my app's textview its adding a  prefix (tel:). 
like : **tel:2234356778876**

I don't want to show tel: in my UITextView ,just the number. I added checking in textview delegate shouldChangeTextInRange method.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if(textView == destination) // destination is the textview
    {
        if([text hasPrefix:@"tel:"])
        {
            text = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"tel:" withString:@""];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

But its not changing anything. textview showing full tel:22xxxxxxxx number. What should be changed in this case?

Note: If I copy number from **Contacts** or **Safari** its working, only number is pasted. But tel: is added for **Notes** app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` argument exists in a context of that delegate function, mutating it won't reflect the result in your `UITextView`.

What you have to do is to check if string contains `"tel:"`, then manually update your `UITextView` contents and return `NO` from that function.

```
if([text hasPrefix:@"tel:"]) {
    NSString *cleanText = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"tel:" withString:@""];
    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:cleanText];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. working. Got problem with Returning YES as it was duplicating the text in textView. Returning NO fixed the problem.

Comment: @MustahsinulMoulaSiam glad to hear that. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you